# Debugging copyproperties when image is null, getting time series for each month

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

I'm trying to make a collection of Landsat8 images for each month of each year, copying the properties of system:time_start of the first image of each respective month, however some months don't have any image, so copyproperties gives an error in those cases

NDVI = my Landsat 8 collection processed

In the following code, im regrouping the images according to month/year

```
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2021);

var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
      var imgmes = NDVI
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
      return imgmes.median()
        .set('month', m).set('year', y)
        .copyProperties(imgmes.first(), ['system:time_start'])
        ;
  });
}).flatten());
print(byMonthYear)
```

How can I set a default time_start for months with 0 images, or how can I ignore months without images?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed adding an if in between

```
var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
      var imgmes = NDVI
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
      var fesh = ee.Algorithms.If(imgmes.first(), imgmes.first().get('system:time_start'),ee.Date('2012-12-31'));
      return imgmes.median()
        .set('month', m).set('year', y)
        .set({'system:time_start': fesh})
//        .copyProperties(imgmes.first(), ['system:time_start'])
        ;
  });
}).flatten());
print(byMonthYear)
```